# Method Range of Object Failure

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to iterate over a table column value to find a value. If the value is found I would like to insert a copy of the row associated with the found value.

The first loop creates a blank row and edits a column value.
The second loop should paste the data directly above each newly created blank row into the blank row below it.

The line throwing the error:
  `ws.Range("ws.Cells(Y, 1): ws.Cells(Y, 8)").Value`

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheet1
Dim x As Variant
Dim Y As Long

Y = 0

  For Each x In ws.[Oper]
    Y = Y + 1
    If InStr(1, x, "1&2-165-200") Or InStr(1, x, "1&2-230-7P") Then
      Cells(Y, 3).Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
      ws.Cells(Y, 3) = "F7015F-1"
    End If
  Next

Y = 0
  For Each x In ws.[Pline]
    Y = Y + 1
    If InStr(1, x, "F7015F-1") Then
        ws.Range("ws.Cells((Y + 1), 1): ws.Cells((Y + 1), 8)").Value = _
        ws.Range("ws.Cells(Y, 1): ws.Cells(Y, 8)").Value
    End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: remove the `"` in the line `ws.Range("ws.Cells(Y, 1): ws.Cells(Y, 8)").Value` and replace `:` with `,`

Comment: Thanks Scott that fixed the issue!